# How do I find a cell that has a modified value from a different cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to take a cell that has some value in it (e.g. B10 is 100), then subtract 5 from that value. (100-5 = 95)

Then I want to pull up the cell that has the value (95), and return the cell that has it (e.g. B5 is 95). Then I want to take that row and pull data from a different column (so pull data from C5 or maybe D5). How do I go about doing this?

This is supposed to be a series of incomplete dates, and I need to look 5 days back from the day. However, since there are gaps in the dates, I can't use normal referencing. For example, if I have the date 1/7/19, then I want 1/2/19. However, if I'm missing data for 1/6/19, then using a normal  formula will return 1/1/19 instead.

I've tried using INDEX and INDIRECT functions, but it hasn't worked yet. I also tried normal cell referencing, but it doesn't work because I need the value in the cell, not the cell itself.

I read up on using the VLOOKUP function, but don't understand how to use it for this application yet.

```
=(INDIRECT("C2:C" & B200 - 100) -C2)/C2
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56692452/edit) to show us your attempts with `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX/MATCH`?

Comment: And add some mock data and expected output.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, but if you need to flexibly handle missing dates, VBA rather than simple spreadsheet functions might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

[I think this is what you are trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eimn0.png)

Essentially you can subtract 5 from your date to always get the date.  then use hlookup (or vlookup if you have your dates down the sheet) to find the correct reference.

here is the formula for cell L5  =HLOOKUP(L2-5,$B$2:$L$3,2,FALSE)